# Why does my variable on the heap sometimes have a higher address than a stack variable

Tags: c

I’m running this code to get the memory address of a stack variable and a heap variable

```
int main() 
{
    int stack_var = 5;
    int *heap_var_ptr = (int*) malloc(4);

    printf("stack_var is at adress %x\n", &stack_var);
    printf("heap_var is at adress  %x\n", heap_var_ptr);

}
```

Output:

```
stack_var is at adress 41a13efc
heap_var is at adress  b09ec2a0
```

Sometimes the heap variable has a higher adress than my stack variable.
Why does this happen I thought the stack starts at a high memory adress and the heap at a low memory adress?

[memory layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKeCn.png)

My os is popOs

Comment: Use `%p` to format the addresses.  You may be getting the less significant 4 bytes of an 8-byte address printed.

Comment: Enable warnings and fix them (that printf format specifier should give you a warning about types.

Comment: By using %p it seems to work. Now the outputted addresses also match with the location of the stack and heap in /proc/<pid>/maps

Comment: I suspect that the "process memory layout" diagram was for an operating system different from the one you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C implementation has 64-bit pointers and 32-bit `unsigned int`, and `%x` is for `unsigned int`. With `%x`, your C implementation is printing only the low 32 bits of the pointers.

Additionally, the behavior of printing a pointer with `%x` is not defined by the C standard.

To print a pointer properly, convert it to `void *` and print it with `%p`:

```
printf("stack_var is at adress %p\n", (void *) &stack_var);
printf("heap_var is at adress  %p\n", (void *) heap_var_ptr);
```